How to get sharepoint link of a MS Teams recording using graph API?
I am able to successfully download the video content of a recording of a MS Teams meeting as follows.
End point:
/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/recordings/{recordingId}/content

Java code:
private static void getRecordingContent(GraphServiceClient cli) {
    var inputStream = cli
            .users()
            .byUserId("c2ad...91")
            .onlineMeetings()
            .byOnlineMeetingId("MSpjMm...kLnYy")
            .recordings()
            .byCallRecordingId("VjIjIz...OWExNjQ=")
            .content()
            .get();

    try (var out = new FileOutputStream("rec.mp4")) {
        inputStream.transferTo(out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

But what I really need is a link that I can share with anyone which will let them play the video in a player. I can get that link manually from MS Teams using the Copy Link option for the recorded file.

Is there any way to get this link by making a graph API call?
The endpoint /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/recordings/{recordingId} gives me a recordingContentUrl. This URL is for an application to download the video content when invoked with proper Authorization header. I'm already doing that using the Java code above. This URL is not the same as a sharepoint URL. The sharepoint URL let's anyone watch the video in a player. You can also configure various permissions (such as allow downloading the video).

An answer to this question gives a REST endpoint to get a URL for a recording: GET /me/online meetings/{meetingId}/recordings/{recordingId}. Does that help?

@jsheeran That endpoint gives you information about the recording, such as createdDateTime and meetingId. The code I posted above uses a variation of that endpoint (/users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/recordings/{recordingId}/content) to download the video. What I'm looking for is a link I can send to anyone which will let them play the video.

The API GET /me/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/recordings can help you fetch the url of the meeting which can be shared to users.
Refer the documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-list-recordings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecordingeventmessagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest.
Currently there is no support to get meeting recording link through Graph API

@Vaibhav-MSFT as I have already noted /me/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/recordings gives you a URL to download the data for the video. This URL doesn't open a player. This cannot be shared with the user since using the URL requires you to set Authorization header.

Graph API doesn't provide any way to get the url that can be shared.
